# Getting the HTTP error 504 (Gateway timeout) with Node.js and Kong API Gateway on EC2 instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, http-get, kong

I'm having problems when trying to call the route of my HTTP GET request.
The same program works when I try to make the same communication with a VM which hosts Kong API Gateway. Then I tried to host it on AWS EC2 instance but I figured out this problem.

I opened the ports 8000 and 8001 creating inbound rules in my security group and I tried to modify the kong.conf file as well to allow communication from anyone, but I can't solve.

This is the server's code which has to communicate with Kong:

```
app.use(cors());

app.get("/api/getorders", async(req, res) => {
  try {
    // Chiamata a Kong API Gateway
    await axios.get(URL_GETALL)
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.status === 200) {  //HTTP OK
        const orders = response.data;
      
        // Invia la risposta al frontend React
        res.status(200).json(orders);
      }
      else {
        console.error("Errore nella chiamata a Kong API Gateway");
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Errore durante la chiamata a Kong API Gateway per richiesta GET:', error.message);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Errore interno del server' });
  } 
});

app.listen(port, '0.0.0.0', () => {
  console.log(`Server avviato su http://localhost:${port}\n`);
});
```

URL_GETALL is a variabile like "http://IP_ADDRESS:PORT/API_ROUTE".

Which could be the problem?